# Add letter and simple quote in french with \autoref to appendix

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, autoref

I have the following rendering by using (french language) :

```
avec $k = k(k_\text{ref},\mu_\text{ref})$ et $\mu=\mu(\mu_\text{ref})$. Le d\'etail de l'obtention de cette relation peut-\^etre trouv\'e dans \autoref{appendix:demoPobs}}

...

\appendix
\chapter{D\'emonstration de l'expression}
\label{appendix:demoPobs}
```

[image]

I would like to make display :

`... peut-être trouvé dans l'Appendice A` with also an `\autoref`. To recap, I would like to add a "l" letter folllowed by a simple quote to get `l'Appendice A` with all word referenced by \autoref (`l'Appendice A`)

Is it posible in Latex to achieve this ?

**UPDATE 1:** sorry for the missing informations.

I am using pdflatex under MacOS HighSierre with :

```
\documentclass[11pt,french,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{psboxit,pstcol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way with `hyperref` only (no use of `cleveref`):

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\appendixautorefname{l'appendice}%
}

\begin{document}
\dots\ dans \autoref{appendix_demoPobs}.

\dots\ dans l'appendice~\ref{appendix_demoPobs}.

\appendix
\section{D\'emonstration de l'expression}
\label{appendix_demoPobs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to achieve your typesetting purely with `hyperref`'s machinery. However, it's not too difficult with the help of the `cleveref` package (which your document loads) and its `\Cref` macro. Note the use of `\Crefname` in the code below to provide the prefix `l'` along with `Appendice`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\Crefname{appendix}{l'Appendice}{les Appendices}

\begin{document}
\dots\ dans \autoref{appendix_demoPobs}.

\dots\ dans \Cref{appendix_demoPobs}.

\dots\ dans l'Appendice~\ref{appendix_demoPobs}.

\appendix
\section{D\'emonstration de l'expression}
\label{appendix_demoPobs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [My answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489386/73317) shows how to do it with pure `hyperref`, for those interested.